# GWT 2.1 and the editor mechanism, how to?

Tags: gwt, editor, gwt2

I'm very confused about the new editor mecanism with GWT 2.1.

I can't understand how to provide errors with a simple TextBox.

For example I want a TextBox where text size is greater than 6 (for a password).

How can I simply provide a delegate to this textbox to handle this verification and use this textbox in the editor mecanism ?

Moreover, I don't understand differences between editor adapters and editor subtypes. How should I use these two features  to create my own editor widget ?

official documentation is here: 
http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html
But it's not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

There's a sample widget in DynaTableRf that implements a [ZIP+4 input box](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/dynatablerf/src/com/google/gwt/sample/dynatablerf/client/widgets/ZipPlusFourBox.java) as a subclass of [ValueBox](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueBox.java).  A custom `Parser` is used to provide the input validation.  The [ValueBoxEditor](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/editor/ui/client/adapters/ValueBoxEditor.java) adapter is used to transform the `ValueBoxBase.getValueOrThrow()` into an `EditorError`.

An "adapter" contains a reusable behavior that isn't tied to editing a specific kind of data.  For example, the [OptionalFieldEditor](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/editor/client/adapters/OptionalFieldEditor.java) and the [ListEditor](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/editor/client/adapters/ListEditor.java) don't really care about the `T` parameterization.  An Editor subtype is primarily concerned with displaying an instance of the `T` type and may or may not embed a complex behavior.